# Sharing of Image and text with Deep linking on facebook in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

Have anyone worked on deep linking in ios 8? I tried to follow facebook.developer tutorial to implement deep linking but is not so much clear.
please suggest me any blog and tutorial or sample code.
Any help will be appriceate.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The startup I'm working in does this exactly. We have a deep linking SDK which takes only 20-30 mins to implement, and after that you can create links on our platform which support Facebook's App Links standard. `[Please find our complete iOS documentation](http://support.hokolinks.com/quickstart/ios/).

Was this helpful?